# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emptyForce' of undefined ( Jqplot )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

On **orientation change** event of phone i replot the graphic:

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
    $('#flot-chart-line-cumul-sales').empty();
    setTimeout(function() {                                    
        plotLineSales.replot({resetAxes:true});
    }, 200);
}
```

jqplot launch this **error** in console in the file **jqplot.pointLabels.min.js** at this point **t._elems[w].emptyForce()**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emptyForce' of undefined
```

FYI: maybe can help, this is the point label code of jqplot:

```
    series:[
            {
                label:'Open + Closed', 
                color:' #4BB2C5',
                pointLabels:
                {
                    show:true,
                    ypadding: 7,
                    stackedValue: false,
                    hideZeros: false,
                    formatString:'%d',
                    escapeHTML:false
                }
            },
            {   
                label:'Closed', 
                color:' #EAA228',
                pointLabels:
                {
                    show:true,
                    ypadding: -25,
                    stackedValue: false,
                    hideZeros: false,
                    formatString:'%d',
                    escapeHTML:false
                }
            },

        ],
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: For problems like this, you generally have to switch to a non-minified version of the library, and then use the browser debugger to figure out where in your code the library is getting bad/incorrect input or configuration or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick fix work.

In **jqplot.pointLabels.min.js** i have changed

`t._elems[w].emptyForce()`

with

`if(t._elems[w]) t._elems[w].emptyForce();`